# Why do these answers have such different quality scores?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, low-quality-posts

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102625/problem-with-the-if-statement/7102723#7102723) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095697/how-can-i-convert-a-json-text-array-to-a-javascript-array/7095736#7095736) answers recently came up in the low-quality filter:

[image]

I'm wondering why there's such a gap in the calculated quality score. Is it because one of the answers is a single code block, and the other also contains regular text? Still, I'm not sure why the difference would be so big. I would personally say the answers are of about the same quality. Should we be trying to improve the heuristics here?

Comment: The SO crew has said multiple times they aren't going to publicize details of how the filters work.  If they could then people could just skirt around them that much more easily.